# Object.freeze doesnt prevent object from being reinitialized?

Tags: javascript, security, object

Working on some script for an application - I'm not trying to make my client-side code *secure*, but I am trying to put in enough security that anyone with a console can't walk by and effortlessly overwrite it.

Consider this example:

```
var config = {};
Object.defineProperty(config, "gridSize", { value : 64, writable : false });
Object.freeze(config);
```

I'd expect this to create an object `config,` with a property `gridSize` set to `64` that can't be overwritten - and then prevent config from being modified with `Object.freeze`.

Sure enough, when I try to penetrate this script in the console, it holds fast:

```
> config.gridSize
< 64
> config.gridSize = 32
< 32
> config.gridSize
< 64
```

But when I attempt to just reset the object directly:

```
> config = {}
< Object
> config.gridSize = 32
< 32
> config.gridSize
< 32
```

I thought `Object.freeze` was supposed to prevent exactly this? Am I doing something wrong, or just misunderstanding its purpose?

Comment: I don't get the "faulty" behaviour in FF linux. After `config.gridSize = 32;`, `config.gridSize;` still says 64.

Comment: Might just be chrome then - thanks for trying to reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re misunderstanding its purpose. `Object.freeze` prevents an object completely from being modified, and it’s doing its job. What you’re doing there is making another object. The original object hasn’t changed (well, until it’s destroyed), but it has moved. Variables are just containers, and they invariably vary.

You can use a `const`, which is not universally supported. (It’s officially part of ECMAScript 6, but not ECMAScript 5.)

If your property actually looks like that, by the way, a simple

```
const config = Object.freeze({
    gridSize: 64
});
```

works.

For a “portable” solution, you can define it on the global object (but that’s not pretty):

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "config", {
    value: Object.freeze({ gridSize: 64 }),
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
});
```

Comment: Excellent answer, `const` was exactly what I was looking for! Hurts a little bit that I'm leaving out IE10-, but thankfully that's not part of the project spec in the first place.